# TADOConnection.Close - connection still active on MS-SQL server

Tags: sql-server, delphi, ado

I have several Delphi programs (XE3), that use a TADOConnection to connect to a MS-SQL Server.
I recently checked the connections in the "MS SQL Server Management Studio"'s  process list.

- When the program starts, the connection is inactive, no connection in
  the server's process list.
- When I open the connection it's shown in the process list - as
  expected.
- When I close the connection (definitely the property "Connected"
  returns FALSE), the connection is still shown on the servers process
  list.

On the server the Connection is not closed until I close the program.

Is there a way to close the TADOConnection in a way that really removes the connection on the server without exiting the program?

Comment: Looks like normal connection pooling behavior. I would expect the physical connection to be closed after a couple of minutes of inactivity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is connection pooling; and is a good thing.

But if you really want to hurt performance, you can opt-out of connection pooling features by adding the request to your connection string:

```
Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=myServerAddress;Initial Catalog=myDataBase;
User ID=myUsername;Password=correct horse battery stapler;OLE DB Services=-2;
```

These **`OLE DB Services`** options are documented on MSDN:

> [Pooling in the Microsoft Data Access Components](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms810829.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) *([archive](http://archive.is/1Ke3k))*
>
> ```
> OLE DB Services  Services enabled
> ===============  ==================================================
> -1               All services (the default)
> -2               All services except pooling
> -4               All services except pooling and auto-enlistment
> -5               All services except client cursor
> -6               All services except client cursor and pooling
>  0               No services
> ```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the enlightenment!
Now I know, that I can just ignore those as they are not reason to poor programming.